# Can't figure out which equation to integrate in order to get velocity on the $y$ axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

[image]

Known: V velocity, a = positive constant, $ y = ax^2 $

Left side: $y = {dVy \over dt} {dt \over dy} \\ \int ydy = \int dVy \\ {y^2 \over 2} = Vy$
Right side: $y = {dVy \over dt} {dt \over dx} \\ \int ydx = \int dVy \\ \int ax^2 dx = \int dVy \\ a {x^3 \over 3} = Vy$

I apologise if the question is too simple, but I returned to physics after a pause and I'm having a few issues with some basic concepts.

I just can't seem to figure out which side is correct and which is incorrect, and why. Both seem entirely mathematically correct (maybe I'm wrong though), but obviously they can't both be correct since (even when inserting the value of $y$ into the left result), they give entirely different results.

My assumption is that the right one is correct because $y$ is defined as $ax^2$ so I can only integrate it with respect to $x$ (so $\text{d}x$). But isn't it technically correct that y is also, well, defined as $y$? Which means that the left one would also be correct? But on the left, I can tell that, since $a$ is a constant, there's no way it should be squared.

This is my first question, I've been too embarrassed to ask for help but it's gotten to the point where I kind of have to to progress quickly enough. Hopefully it meets the standards of the site, and if not, I apologise and I'll try to do better next time.

[image]

EDIT 1: Learned how to use LaTeX and edited to include it instead of handwriting.

EDIT 2: Inserted the text of the problem as a user asked.

Comment: Your handwriting's a little hard to read. Can write the equations out in LaTeX please?

Comment: It would be good if you could typeset the math with MathJax, here's a guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Aside from the LaTeX/MathJax thing, could you also tell us what the actual homework problem says, in addition to your two attempts to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I put a LaTeX equation and the text of the problem itself. I left out the problem since, well, the "homework help" rules say that I should focus on the concept I have a problem - I'm not just looking for someone to do my homework, I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The right one is definitely the right one, but how did you come with that equation?

$$y= \dfrac{dU_y}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dy}$$

Comment: That's... a very helpful question, actually... I actually didn't realise I was misusing that. I wasn't sure what it was called, so I googled around and I found out that it's called the chain rule and that it only applies in one specific circumstance, this one: http://www.canadaconnects.ca/_quantumphysics/photos/chainrule.png

$f = f(g); g = g(x) \\ {df \over dx} = {df \over dg} {dg \over dx} $

I realised I was using it without paying attention to the condition under which it applies.

Comment: Yes but still, how did you come up with that chain rule? I don't think it stands as itself

Comment: I didn't come up with it, I took an academic break (medical reasons) and was mistaken in thinking that the chain rule applies in all cases, since I vaguely recalled using the chain rule but not WHEN it was applicable. Your question made me realise that the rule actually applies only under a specific circumstance.

Comment: It is generally applied, but $y = \dfrac{dU_y}{dy}$ is not a given equation right? No need to apologize for anything btw

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "it is generally applied"?
And yeah, $y = \dfrac{dU_y}{dy}$ is definitely not given by the problem (nor is it a definition in physics of course).

Answer (score 0):

Let me write $v_x = \dot x$ and $v_y = \dot y$ with the idea that we've actually got two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and dots are $d/dt$ operations on these two functions.

It sounds like you want the acceleration vector $[\ddot x, \ddot y]$, evaluated right when $x=0$. There is a symmetry argument that the $\ddot x = 0$ at this point, and it goes like this: a trajectory of constant speed must always have the acceleration perpendicular to that velocity vector, otherwise we know that this force does work on the particle and work increases the kinetic energy which increases the speed. (You can also get this result if you don't just "see" it by substituting the following expression for $\dot y$ into the expression of constant velocity, $\dot x^2 + \dot y^2 = v^2,$ which an earlier edit of this answer did explicitly. But I think that the preceding argument is much more elegant.)

Furthermore, we know that $\dot x = v$ at this point because all of the velocity must point along the tangent vector to the parabola.

Now to get $\ddot y$ we need to take two derivatives of $y(t) = a~[x(t)]^2.$ This will require both the chain and the product rule. Our first derivative uses the chain rule,$$\dot y(t) = 2 a~x(t)~\dot x(t).$$ Our second derivative uses the product rule, $$\ddot y(t) = 2a~\dot x(t)~\dot x(t) + 2a~x(t)~\ddot x(t).$$

Now as we just observed, at $x=0$ we have $\dot x = v$ and $\ddot x = 0$ so that gives your answer right away; the acceleration is $2a~v^2 + 0$.

Comment: CR Drost, velocity must have both x and y components to get a parabolic path.  Why do you state that $v_x = v$ at $x = 0$, implying that there is no y component to velocity at that point?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.

I understand what you're doing as I'm reading it, but I'm not entirely sure I would have been able to notice the same patterns and come to the same conclusions myself. I think the reason is that I might lack some of the mathematical basis for this kind of problem. I think I need to revise and learn more about differential equations. Differential equations is what I should be looking at, right?

Comment: @Robo this is more basic calculus than solving differential equations. Like, if you get good at solving diffyq's that will probably require the sorts of skills needed here, but the more basic question is "what did you expect to be getting from an integral, anyways?" To get to an acceleration from an integral you would need to know the jerk; to get to it from position one basically *has to* do derivatives.

Comment: @CRDrost

Got it! I've already covered all of these things, and have known them in the past, but I took a couple of years off due to medical reasons, and due to a lack of practice, I forgot many of them so I have a lot of holes in my knowledge. I have a month left to prepare (which I plan to use to revise and remember all the basics I need) and I already passed the calculus class, so I think I'll be able to do it.
I'm going to go and revise the math basics and then come back to physics when I do so, and then I'll look over your answer again and ask if I don't understand something. Thanks!

Comment: @Robo That's totally ok! I also left my Bachelor's for medical reasons; then I came back from that and got my Master's. There was definitely a huge gap of practice that I had to make up in just a few months.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved with derivatives and not an integral. Choose one variable as your DOF, like $x$ and express the position in terms of your DOF only

$$\overline{\mathrm{pos}} = \pmatrix{x & a x^2} $$

Since position varies with $x$ and $x$ varies with time, use the chain rule to find velocity

$$\overline{\mathrm{vel}} = \tfrac{\partial}{\partial t} \overline{\rm pos} = \left(\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \overline{\rm pos} \right) \tfrac{\partial x}{\partial t} = \pmatrix{\dot{x} & 2 a \dot{x}}  $$

But we know the velocity is constant $v$, or

$$ \left. v = \| \overline{\rm vel} \| = \dot{x} \sqrt{1+4 a^2 x^2}\;\; \right\} \;\; \dot{x} = \frac{v}{\sqrt{1+4a^2 x^2}} $$

The velocity vector is now a function of $x$ only.

$$ \overline{\rm vel} = \pmatrix{ \frac{v}{\sqrt{1+4 a^2 x^2}} & \frac{2 a x v}{\sqrt{1+4 a^2 x^2}} } $$

So the acceleration vector is found again with the chain rule

$$ \overline{\rm acc} = \tfrac{\partial }{\partial t} \overline{\rm vel} = \left( \tfrac{\partial }{\partial x} \overline{\rm vel} \right) \dot{x} $$

Without giving out the answer, you know $\dot{x}$ from above, and thus you can evaluate the velocity vector at any $x$.

To get the acceleration magnitude just do $a = \| \overline{\rm acc} \|$.